# What is the equivalent of this MySQL query to MS SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Please refer to this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f435e/15 .

I want to have this query running on MS SQL Server. This is currently working on my MySQL, but unfortunately we are migrating to MS SQL Server.

Please help.

Comment: First of all, SQLFiddle is amazing, and thank you for including it - it always makes answering any SQL questions easier. However, by Stack Overflow rules, each question should be self-sufficient; the link is a nice bonus, but all relevant code should be in the question itself. Additionally, you might want to describe the purpose of the code in words.

Comment: actually if you see the link, you can actually see what i mean.

Comment: I know what you mean. You apparently didn't read what *I* mean. Link-only questions are lazy and [discouraged by SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." Add your code to the question. And you will get more people willing to answer if the intent is clearly spelled out rather than if people need to read the code.

Comment: May I know what version of SQL-SERVER are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, no problem for create and insert query.

But for the select query, you may try the following query in SQL SERVER:

```
select
       pin
     , in_datetime
     , out_datetime
     , CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(SECOND,in_datetime,out_datetime) * 1000, 0), 114) as duration
from (
      select
            pin
          , date_time as in_datetime
          , (select TOP 1 l.date_time from logs as l
             where l.date_time > logs.date_time
             and l.mode = 'OUT'
             order by l.date_time ASC) as out_datetime
      from logs
      where mode = 'IN'
    ) as relog
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table logs (Pin varchar(20),Mode varchar(100),Date_time datetime(3));
insert into logs values ('16514','IN','2015-06-12 16:37:46');
insert into logs values ('16514','OUT','2015-06-13 06:37:46');
insert into logs values ('16514','IN','2015-06-13 16:37:46');
insert into logs values ('16514','OUT','2015-06-14 06:37:46');

select  pin, in_datetime,
out_datetime,
date_format(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,in_datetime,out_datetime)),
'%H:%i:%S') as duration
from (
      select
            pin
          , date_time as in_datetime
          , (select l.date_time from logs as l
             where l.date_time > logs.date_time
             and l.mode = 'OUT'
             order by l.date_time ASC
             LIMIT 1) as out_datetime
      from logs
      where mode = 'IN'
    ) as
```

Comment: OP wants to convert from MySQL to SQL Server.